# Debug Rest API in Eclipse

Tags: rest, jira

I am writing a program to connect with JIRA and create tickets automatically.
For this i used JIRA rest API. The code is done in Eclipse-Kepler using java as a stand alone program.

For some request, this program is throwing "Bad Request" and response code "400".
I want to debug what is wrong with a particular request. Is there any plug in to debug that?
I tried using Rest client in eclipse, but its asking for URL to hit in this tool.
I want if I run my program as Java, some tool can show me the required debug statements.

Thanks,
Arfeen.

Comment: Have you tried replicating the calls that eclipse would be calling using Poster to check whether or not you would be getting that error

Comment: Hi user2573153, Thank you for your prompt response. Well, I am new to this. Can you please show me the path to check that?

Comment: Yeah, here it is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/poster/ You can then double check that the REST service you are using actually works normally to determine if your code or in the service

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will check it. Between, same request is working for one server but not working with another. I suspect there is prob with mandatory field or role. This is why i want to debug.

Comment: And as i said, my program is stand alone, meaning it runs as java program in eclipse. So the suggested tool will work only for web based program. Sadly this is not my cup of coffee.

Comment: In order to create the tickets in JIRA, you must be hitting some endpoint on their servers. I was suggesting to test that one using Poster to make sure that the tickets get created.

Comment: I am using in this way—
Call for JIRA api -http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue
Passing JSON string –
String input = "{\"fields\": {\"project\": {  \"key\": \"ABC\" },\"summary\": \"Summary to test\", \"description\": \"Creation of Request\", \"issuetype\": { \"name\": \"Task\" } } }";
   
      
ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, input);

Now if I see the response code, its coming as 400. Tell me how to pass this using tool poster?
May its inane question, but just today I started using rest api. Thank you once again.

Comment: Going to the https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e1196  Jira Docs , you should be getting an error message in the Response body. You can programatically retrieve it using response.getEntity()
or from poster by passing in the URL into URL box and the json in the body (and pressing post)